# Class extends value [object Object] is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js

I'm starting to learn Node.js recently. I currently have a backend project using Express and Firestore to handle frontend petitions and i'm trying to implement classes and subclasses since the project is becoming bigger, so i want to order methods and divide them into files, but for some reason, i can't extend the main class, which in this case is *Server*, on the subclass *RouteProducts*.

This is what i tried so far:

index.js:

```
//Importing subclasses
let RouteProducts = require('./requests/routeProducts.js');

class Server {
    constructor(_app,_db){
        this.app = _app;
        this.db = _db;
        this.initExpress();
        this.start();
    }

    initExpress(){
        this.app.use(express.json());
        this.app.use(cors());
    }

    start(){
        this.app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => console.log("Running on port "+process.env.PORT));
    }
}


module.exports = Server;

//Initializing all classes in order
new Server(express(),config);
new RouteProducts();
```

routeProducts.js:

```
let Server = require('../index.js');
const handleProducts = require('./handleCRUD/handleProducts.js');

class RouteProducts extends Server {
    constructor(_app,_db){
        super(_app,_db);
        this.getAllProducts();
    }

    getAllProducts(){
        _app.get("/read/product/", async (req, res) => {
            await handleProducts.getAllProducts(_db,res);
        });
    }

}

module.exports = RouteProducts;
```

When i run the project with *npx nodemon index.js*, i get this error below (even if i comment *new RouteProducts();*):

```
class RouteProducts extends Server {
                            ^


TypeError: Class extends value [object Object] is not a constructor or null
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Estaniel\Documents\Proyectos\source-shop_back\requests\routeProducts.js:5:29)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1091:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:938:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1115:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:130:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Estaniel\Documents\Proyectos\source-shop_back\index.js:10:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1241:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1295:10)

Node.js v20.7.0
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

I searched a lot about this but i couldn't find what's the problem there. I've changed *module.exports = Server* into *module.exports = {Server}* but that didn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is that you have a circular dependency structure: `index.js` requires `routeProducts.js` and `routeProducts.js` requires `index.js`. Assuming you run `index.js`, Node.js sees the `require()` call and loads the `routeProducts.js`. When Node.js sees `require('../index.js')` in that file, it won't try to load `index.js` again. (That would cause infinite recursion.) Instead, it returns `index.js`'s `module.exports`, which at that point wasn't yet assigned to. See [the docs](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#cycles) for more information about this behavior.

You can fix this by either moving the `Server` class to a different file or by assigning to `module.exports` before calling `require()`.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I still don't get how to use classes properly but i fully understood your answer. I'll see what i can do.